# How to properly order dates from my app's database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm having trouble getting event dates pulled from my database to render in proper order. I'm using bootstrap-datepicker in my simple_form for the user to use. My events controller currently is:

````
 ```def index
        @events = Event.order(start_date: :asc).where('start_date::date >= CURRENT_DATE')
    end```
````

The events do get rendered to the page with the correct date but they seem to only be getting ordered by month and ignoring the year. For example the events taking place in January of 2021 will be listed above March 2020, because January comes before March.

I've tried looking for how the order method in ruby works as well as searching as other posts, but I haven't been successful. Any thoughts?

Logs:

````
```Started GET "/events" for ::1 at 2019-11-25 10:26:28 -0800
Processing by EventsController#index as HTML
  Rendering events/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/events/index.html.erb:10
  Event Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (start_date::date >= CURRENT_DATE) ORDER BY "events"."start_date" ASC
  ↳ app/views/events/index.html.erb:27
  Rendered events/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 174ms (Views: 171.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)```
````

application.js:

````
```//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
$(function() {
    $('input.datepicker').data({behaviour: "datepicker"}).datepicker();
});```
````

simple_form:

````
```<div class="event-box col-5 offset-3">
    <br/>
    <h1 align="center" style="font-size: 25px;">Create New Event</h1>
    <%= simple_form_for @event do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :title %>
        <%= f.input :start_date, as: :string, input_html: { class: "datepicker" }%>
        <%= f.input :end_date, as: :string, input_html: { class: "datepicker" }%>
        <%= f.input :location %>
        <%= f.input :details %>
        <br />
        <div align="center">
            <%= f.submit 'Create', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
    <% end %>   
    <br/>
</div>

<script>
$('#datepicker').datepicker({format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'});
</script>```
````

events table:

````
```create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "start_date"
    t.string "end_date"
    t.string "location"
    t.text "details"
    t.integer "event_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "event"
    t.index ["event_id"], name: "index_events_on_event_id"
  end```
````

Comment: Could you please add the query being ran in the console when the view is loaded

Comment: Is that the same as the info being put out in the server?

Comment: When you load the page it should show you the exact query being ran in your logs. When you use active record to build queries in your logs it will show you something like `SELECT * FROM events WHERE 'start_date::date>=CURRENT_DATE' ORDER BY start_date ASC`

Comment: Oops, scratch that last comment. I see what you are trying to do. It looks like the query is correct, are you sure nothing front end is modifying the order? Any JS?

Comment: I'll go through my files and edit the post with anything relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `start_date` is saved as a string rather than a time.  When you try to sort by the string it just alphabetizes the output so all January get grouped together.

if you change:

```
t.string "start_date"
```

to:

```
t.date_time "start_date"
```

it should work.  You will have to migrate the existing data obviously.

Comment: Thank you! I'll go try that

Comment: That seems to work! I never thought of needing to change the column type. Thanks so much!

Comment: Proper field definitions in a database make a world of difference in how a database behaves and performs. It's important to go through tutorials for your DBM to learn how to create the schemas otherwise you could write an application that creeps along, consumes huge amounts of CPU or disk, or is so inflexible you can't do anything but the bare essentials.